# Different arg formatting for definitions vs invocations

Tags: f#, code-formatting

I'm curious why primary constructor args must be indented beyond the opening paren, in the type definition, yet may be indented with the type name when invoked.

```
type AnIncrediblyLaboriouslyEternallyLongTypeName(arg1, arg2,
      arg3, arg4) = //WARNING: Possible incorrect indentation
  class end

let x = AnIncrediblyLaboriouslyEternallyLongTypeName(
          1, 2, 3, 4) //works
```

The solution is to indent the args beyond the left edge of your second monitor:

```
type AnIncrediblyLaboriouslyEternallyLongTypeName(arg1, arg2,
                                                  arg3, arg4) = 
  class end
```

I'm wondering why the rules are different in these two scenarios.

This also applies to methods. I just chose primary constructors as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recall, but note that this

```
type AnIncrediblyLaboriouslyEternallyLongTypeName
        (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) = // works
  class end
```

is also allowed.

Comment: I still can't figure out why C# code formatting doesn't work. :-)

Comment: It probably doesn't work because the compiler parser doesn't handle such cases :). In this case it seems that '(' creates a new block and if the ')' is not in same level then it doesn't work